# OpenGL ES2.0 Objects added to array after OnSurfaceCreated not being drawn

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I have an array of objects that I'm cycling through and drawing in the OnDraw method. When I add these objects to the array in OnSurfaceCreated the objects appear appear fine, they're cycled through and drawn on screen. However if I add the same objects to the array in a method called by a UI event it doesn't. What gives?

```
 @Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mtrxMultiplied, 0, mtrxProj, 0, mtrxView, 0);

    mBackground.draw(mtrxMultiplied, board.getmContext());

    for (int i = 0; i < stickemArray.size(); i++){
        stickemArray.get(i).draw(mtrxMultiplied, board.getmContext());
        Log.v("stickems being drawn", Float.toString(stickemArray.get(i).getPositionX()) + "/" + Float.toString(stickemArray.get(i).getPositionY()));
    }
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig eglConfig) {

    mBackground = new Background(board.getmContext());

    stickemArray.add(new Stickem(500f, 200f, board.getmContext()));

    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1);

}

public void addStickem(Stickem stickem){
    Log.v("add stickem in renderer", "activated");
    stickemArray.add(stickem);
    stickemArray.add(new Stickem(400, 200, board.getmContext()));

}
```

For the example here, the object I create with the co-ordinates 500/200 works fine, but not the object with 400/200. The object is being correctly added to the array and the call to draw it is being correctly passed on to the object but it just won't appear on screen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out my issue, please correct me if I'm wrong! All the objects (ie the objects vertex/index/texture buffers) need to be created in OnSurfaceCreated or it simply won't work.

Instead of adding new objects to the array at runtime, I created an array of "empty" objects to start with in OnSurfaceCreated and created a method that fills them with data after it's initialized. The for loop I set in the renderer then looks for non-empty objects in the array and draws them.